# Faster increments with longer UIButton hold duration

Tags: ios, button, uibutton

I have a label that displays a number. The user can increment or decrement the value of that label using two buttons. What id like though is if the user holds either button the value will either increment or decrement faster and faster. For example held for 1 second 1x faster, 2 seconds 2x faster, 3 seconds 3x faster, and so on.

This is what I've tried but doesn't work as it doesn't continue calling the method and you can't see you assign more then one `UILongGessureRecognizer` on a button. I need another approach. Any ideas?

In my viewDidLoad

```
    longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(incrementTwoX)];
    longerPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(incrementThreeX)];
    [longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:1.5];
    [longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:3];
    //add long and longer press gestures to ALL buttons
    [weightLeftButton addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [weightLeftButton addGestureRecognizer:longerPressGesture];
    [weightRightButton addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [weightRightButton addGestureRecognizer:longerPressGesture];

-(void)incrementTwoX{
    NSLog(@"Holding");// doesn't get called Im guessing because you can't assign more then one long gesture recognizer to a button

}
-(void)incrementThreeX{
    NSLog(@"Holding Longer");

}
- (IBAction)weightRight:(id)sender {
    if([weightLabel.text  isEqual: @"Not Specified"]) weightLabel.text = 0;
    double value = [weightLabel.text doubleValue] + 0.1;
    weightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value];
}
```

My Progress..

Heres whats happens the first time I click the button and hold.. it'll only change the label from Not Specified to 0(Zero). Next time I click and hold it works PERFECTLY. Then anytime after it only increments by 2 with every click and hold nothing more. Can you see what could be the problem? With the 2 increments to specify more. Ill click and hold and you'll see no change to the label no matter how long you hold. Then when you let go of the button(after any duration of holding, even a fast click) you see the label increment by 2

```
- (void) increment:(UIButton*)currentButton label:(UILabel*)currentLabel{

    currentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", _counter++];

    // if the button is still pressed, increment again in a little while:
    if ( currentButton.state != UIControlStateNormal ){
        NSLog(@"incrementing %d", _counter);
        CGFloat delay = 1.0/(CGFloat)_counter;

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)( delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self increment:currentButton label:currentLabel];
        });
    }
}

- (IBAction)weightRight:(id)sender {
    [self increment:weightRightButton label:weightLabel];
}
```

This is what ill log. Look at how it increments just like I want after the first click. I let go at 91. Then it only increments by 2 even though the if statement is only called once. Also look at the times of the later logs when incremented by 2 doesn't matter if i hold for a long time or just do some quick taps. What is happening?

```
2014-04-05 11:40:37.960 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 1
2014-04-05 11:40:38.961 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 2
2014-04-05 11:40:39.463 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 3
2014-04-05 11:40:39.798 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 4
2014-04-05 11:40:40.049 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 5
2014-04-05 11:40:40.250 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 6
2014-04-05 11:40:40.419 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 7
2014-04-05 11:40:40.563 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 8
2014-04-05 11:40:40.690 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 9
2014-04-05 11:40:40.803 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 10
2014-04-05 11:40:40.904 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 11
2014-04-05 11:40:40.997 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 12
2014-04-05 11:40:41.081 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 13
2014-04-05 11:40:41.160 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 14
2014-04-05 11:40:41.233 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 15
2014-04-05 11:40:41.301 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 16
2014-04-05 11:40:41.365 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 17
2014-04-05 11:40:41.425 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 18
2014-04-05 11:40:41.481 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 19
2014-04-05 11:40:41.535 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 20
2014-04-05 11:40:41.586 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 21
2014-04-05 11:40:41.636 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 22
2014-04-05 11:40:41.683 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 23
2014-04-05 11:40:41.728 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 24
2014-04-05 11:40:41.771 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 25
2014-04-05 11:40:41.813 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 26
2014-04-05 11:40:41.853 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 27
2014-04-05 11:40:41.891 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 28
2014-04-05 11:40:41.929 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 29
2014-04-05 11:40:41.964 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 30
2014-04-05 11:40:41.999 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 31
2014-04-05 11:40:42.033 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 32
2014-04-05 11:40:42.066 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 33
2014-04-05 11:40:42.097 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 34
2014-04-05 11:40:42.128 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 35
2014-04-05 11:40:42.158 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 36
2014-04-05 11:40:42.187 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 37
2014-04-05 11:40:42.216 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 38
2014-04-05 11:40:42.244 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 39
2014-04-05 11:40:42.271 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 40
2014-04-05 11:40:42.297 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 41
2014-04-05 11:40:42.323 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 42
2014-04-05 11:40:42.348 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 43
2014-04-05 11:40:42.373 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 44
2014-04-05 11:40:42.398 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 45
2014-04-05 11:40:42.420 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 46
2014-04-05 11:40:42.443 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 47
2014-04-05 11:40:42.466 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 48
2014-04-05 11:40:42.489 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 49
2014-04-05 11:40:42.510 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 50
2014-04-05 11:40:42.532 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 51
2014-04-05 11:40:42.553 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 52
2014-04-05 11:40:42.574 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 53
2014-04-05 11:40:42.593 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 54
2014-04-05 11:40:42.613 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 55
2014-04-05 11:40:42.632 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 56
2014-04-05 11:40:42.652 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 57
2014-04-05 11:40:42.671 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 58
2014-04-05 11:40:42.690 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 59
2014-04-05 11:40:42.708 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 60
2014-04-05 11:40:42.725 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 61
2014-04-05 11:40:42.743 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 62
2014-04-05 11:40:42.761 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 63
2014-04-05 11:40:42.777 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 64
2014-04-05 11:40:42.794 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 65
2014-04-05 11:40:42.811 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 66
2014-04-05 11:40:42.827 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 67
2014-04-05 11:40:42.843 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 68
2014-04-05 11:40:42.859 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 69
2014-04-05 11:40:42.875 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 70
2014-04-05 11:40:42.891 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 71
2014-04-05 11:40:42.907 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 72
2014-04-05 11:40:42.922 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 73
2014-04-05 11:40:42.938 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 74
2014-04-05 11:40:42.953 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 75
2014-04-05 11:40:42.968 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 76
2014-04-05 11:40:42.982 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 77
2014-04-05 11:40:42.996 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 78
2014-04-05 11:40:43.009 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 79
2014-04-05 11:40:43.023 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 80
2014-04-05 11:40:43.037 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 81
2014-04-05 11:40:43.051 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 82
2014-04-05 11:40:43.064 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 83
2014-04-05 11:40:43.077 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 84
2014-04-05 11:40:43.090 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 85
2014-04-05 11:40:43.103 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 86
2014-04-05 11:40:43.116 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 87
2014-04-05 11:40:43.119 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 88
2014-04-05 11:40:47.107 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 91
2014-04-05 11:40:52.233 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 93
2014-04-05 11:40:55.157 Stream Craft[1090:60b] Ad did load
2014-04-05 11:40:56.271 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 95
2014-04-05 11:41:00.233 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 97
2014-04-05 11:41:03.849 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 99
2014-04-05 11:41:10.193 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 101
2014-04-05 11:41:11.319 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 103
2014-04-05 11:41:12.122 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 105
2014-04-05 11:41:12.373 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 107
2014-04-05 11:41:12.544 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 109
2014-04-05 11:41:12.700 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 111
2014-04-05 11:41:12.802 Stream Craft[1090:60b] incrementing 113
```

Also this is how my button and label are set up...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *weightLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *weightRightButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *weightLeftButton;
```

Also the sent event is 'Touch Up Inside' for my button if that matters?

Comment: what have you tried? if you peruse the events available to you from a UIButton, you'll see the events you need are being raised. Give it a spin and post your code here if you run into trouble.

Comment: You're calling twice `setMinimumPressDuration:` on `longPressGesture ` and zero on `longerPressGesture`. A typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**  updated with a slightly better example.

If you already have a UIButton I wouldn't mess with gesture recognizers.  All you need to do is continually check if the button is still pressed, and if it is increment your counter.  You can decrease the time between checks so that the counter speed ramps up from slow to fast, as you describe.

The trick here is to use GCD to dispatch some work to be done after a delay, via dispatch_after().

Here's a complete solution.  If you need a custom ramp up time (as you discuss in the question) just record the time the button was first pressed and calculate the time to the next increment based on the total time elapsed.

```
@interface TSViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UILabel*   _label;

    IBOutlet UIButton*  _button;

    int                 _counter;

    NSDate*             _start;
}
@end

@implementation TSViewController

- (void) increment
{
    // if the button is still pressed, increment again in a little while:
    if ( _button.state != UIControlStateNormal )
    {
        _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", _counter++];

        CGFloat elapsed = MAX(1, fabs( [_start timeIntervalSinceNow] ) );

        CGFloat delay = 0.9/elapsed;

        NSLog( @"%.3lf, delay: %.3lf", elapsed , delay);

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)( delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self increment];
        });
    }
}

- (IBAction) touchDown:(UIButton*)sender
{
    _start = [NSDate date];

    [self increment];
}

@end
```

Comment: Heres whats happens the first time I click the button and hold.. it'll only change the label from Not Specified to 0(Zero). Next time I click and hold it works PERFECTLY. Then anytime after it only increments by 2 with every click and hold nothing more. Can you see what could be the problem?

Comment: With the 2 increments to specify more. Ill click and hold and you'll see no change to the label no matter how long you hold. Then when you let go of the button(after any duration of holding, even a fast click) you see the label increment by 2

Comment: It sounds like you have some other stuff going on.  Did you try this in a clean project with just a button and a label?  How about you add some logging so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Look at my log. I have posted my code only changes I made to yours was i addd parameters to your incrementing method

Comment: Also I like to mention yes this is a clean project the only thing going at the moment now is the ad banner but even if I stop that it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I updated the sample code to demonstrate using time (vs counter value) to adjust the ramp up.  You can use whatever ramp up algorithm you want, or adjust the constants I used.  Also, please make sure you're capturing the "touch down" event (vs. "touch up inside").

Comment: Perfect thank you! I just have one last problem if I want to increment by 0.1 how is this done? I have changed my counter variable type to float and changed counter++ to counter + 0.1.. What happens is the label only shows 0.1 then nothing after..?

Comment: Did you change the format specifier in the stringWithFormat call?  For float should be %f, vs %d for integer.

Comment: Yes i have it at %.1f

Comment: I got it all i had to do was put _counter = _counter + 0.1;... doing the calculating separately instead of in the stringWithFormat call works.. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: TomSwift answered in oBJC :(

Comment: @BooberBunz it was April 2014.  Swift didn't arrive until June of that year IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no need to initialize UILongPressGestureRecognizer twice,you could try following approach:-

- When you receive call first time in UILongPressGestureRecognizer's selector
  method, save the current timestamp.
- When you receive call second/Third time, after saving current timestamp compare it with the first saved timestamp.
- Now multiply the value with the difference of timestamp.

By this way you can keep on increasing the speed of value increment/decrement.

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp? Also the selector method doesn't continuously get called so there won't be a second or third time?

Comment: A timestamp would simply to save `[NSDate date]` once. Then use a `NSTimer` to get your method continually called (maybe 10 times per second). And lastly make sure to `invalidate` the timer when the button gets released.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIStepper` control.

Connect this function to its `ValueChanged` event:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // `nameLabel` defined in .h file
    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, 100.0f, 135.0f, 36.0f)];
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
}

-(IBAction)valChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    [nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", ((UIStepper *)sender).value]];
}
```

Implement this code and hold this steppers `+` for few seconds.

Comment: thanks but I don't want to use a stepper.. doesn't work with the user interface style Im going for